# How to iterate over multiple maps and get their values? - C++

Tags: c++, maps

so I have 3 multimaps that all have the same keys (Which in this case are Dates), and the values they represent are different for each map. I know how to create an iterator and iterate over one map, and then use that iterator to get the values for that map. However, how would I iterate over all 3 maps and get their values into the variables I need? I'm confused because if I use one iterator to iterate over all 3 maps, that iterator only gives me the values for the map that I created the iterator for, and I feel that creating 3 for loops just for this is a bit much. Any ideas?

```
    multimap<Date, float> mapOption4WindSpeed;
    multimap<Date, float> mapOption4Temperature;
    multimap<Date, double> mapOption4Solar;


    cout << "Please enter year (xxxx): " << endl;
    cin >> year;

    Date newDate;
    newDate.SetDay("1");
    newDate.SetDay("1");
    newDate.SetDay(year);

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        mapOption4WindSpeed.insert(make_pair(windlog[i].d, windlog[i].speed.GetSpeed()));
        mapOption4WindSpeed.insert(make_pair(windlog[i].d, windlog[i].temp.GetTemperature()));
        mapOption4Solar.insert(make_pair(windlog[i].d, windlog[i].solar.GetSolar()));
    }

    multimap<Date, float>::iterator itS = mapOption4WindSpeed.find(newDate);
    multimap<Date, float>::iterator itT = mapOption4Temperature.find(newDate);
    multimap<Date, double>::iterator itSol = mapOption4Solar.find(newDate);

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) //Loop through entire array to check if the input matches the year
    {

        if(itS != mapOption4WindSpeed.end()) //This statement and the above is where I am confused
        {

            //Bunch of operations in here

        }
```

My Struct:

```
typedef struct
{

    Date d;
    Time t;
    Weather speed;
    Weather solar;
    Weather temp;

} WindLogType;
```

And then I used a Vector of the struct to access values:

```
Vector<WindLogType> windlog;
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're trying to do. You are doing `.find` to check if the `newDate` is in the map. What is the loop for exactly?

Comment: I apologize, it is just my work in progress, you can assume that I am basically stuck trying to figure out how to loop over values for 3 maps instead of 1. The reason I want to do this, is because each of the 3 maps have the exact same keys and therefore size as well, but the values they hold are different and I would like to loop over the maps and retrieve values from each map in the same loop. Hope that makes sense

Comment: But I'm not sure why you need a loop for that. Assuming the find is successful, `itS->second` will give you the windspeed.

Comment: I need a loop, because there are duplicate date values (hence the multimap) in my file all with different corresponding values. Usually, I loop by creating an iterator for a specific map and loop over that map but now, I cant create a single iterator to loop over all 3 maps because that iterator would only give me values for the map I created it for. Wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

> so I have 3 multimaps that all have the same keys (Which in this case are Dates), and the values they represent are different for each map.

Unless you have a very strong reason to use three `multimap`s, I would advise creating a single `multimap`.

```
struct MyData
{
   float windSpeed;
   float temperature;
   double solar;
};

std::multimap<Date,  MyData> mapOfMyData;
```

That will make accessing all the data corresponding to a `Date` easy.

Comment: if you consolidate all the information, how can you find whether a pair of (data, temperature) exists in the multimap?

Comment: Before trying to use maps, I had a struct (which I will include now in my question), and then I created a Vector of this struct. So i was accessing values using this Vector of the struct. Will I be able to include the entire Vector into my map instead then? How could I do this?

Comment: @madhur4127, given a key, you can find out whether the map contains any elements with the key. You can use `std::multimap::lower_bound` and `std::multimap::upper_bound` to iterate over them.

Comment: @thedafferg `map<Date, vector<struct>> my_map` would work. You can add to this by `my_map[date].push_back(...)`.

Comment: When I declare it like this `multimap<Date, Vector<struct>> testMap;`, i get the errors template argument 1 and 2 are invalid. Note that Vector is a custom class that simply encapsulates the std::vector so that can't be the reason

Comment: @thedafferg, that's a different question. I think it will be better to ask that in a different post.

Comment: @RSahu I will do that once my 1hr 30 mins restriction is up, thank you for your help